# AVPlayer working with .m4a extension but not with .aac using AVAssetExportSession

Tags: swift, avplayer, aac, avassetexportsession, m4a

I'm working on an app that records audio tracks with `AVAudioRecorder`, I save the file with the `.m4a` extension, and finally I move that file changing the extension to `.aac`, and it works perfectly. I can play it without problems using `AVPlayer`.

But my problem is that, when merging the recordings into one track, I export a composition using `AVAssetExportSession` (or `SDAVAssetExportSession`), and `AVPlayer` is not able to play the exported file (not even QuickTime or `AVAudioPlayer`, but it works in Audacity, VLC, Preview app, etc.). It DOES work when changing the extension back to `.m4a`. I'm trying do the same like I do with the recorder, I export to `.m4a` and then change the file extension to `.aac`.

I'm trying to always use `.aac` file formats to keep consistency, and to not mess around with extensions, considering that it could also impact other platforms (Android & Web).

I have investigated how to "convert" `.m4a` to a fully working `.aac` but I haven't found much.

This works as expected:

```
guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A) else {
   print("Error")
   return
}
let saveUrlM4A = FilesHelper.getRandomFileUrlInTemp(fileExtension: "m4a")
exportSession.outputFileType = .m4a
exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
exportSession.outputURL = saveUrlM4A
exportSession.audioMix = audioMix
exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
   if let error = exportSession.error {
      print("Error")
   } else {
      let saveUrlAAC = FilesHelper.getRandomFileUrlInTemp(fileExtension: "aac")
      try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: saveUrlM4A, to: saveUrlAAC)
   }
}
```

Then:

```
player.replaceCurrentItem(with: AVPlayerItem(url: audioFileUrl))
player.play()
```

Works for the `.m4a` URL, but not for the `.aac`.

Is there a way to get a fully working `.aac` file without changing the extension to `.m4a`?